# AS3 code to mute music on incoming calls affects other phone actions

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

I am using this code:

```
if (Capabilities.cpuArchitecture=="ARM") {
    NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, handleActivate, false, 0, true);
    NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE , handleDeactivate, false, 0, true); 
}

function handleActivate(event:Event):void {
var transformGlobal1:SoundTransform=new SoundTransform();   
    transformGlobal1.volume=1;
    flash.media.SoundMixer.soundTransform=transformGlobal1;
    NativeApplication.nativeApplication.systemIdleMode=SystemIdleMode.KEEP_AWAKE;
}

function handleDeactivate(event:Event):void {
var transformGlobal2:SoundTransform=new SoundTransform();       
    transformGlobal2.volume=0;
    flash.media.SoundMixer.soundTransform=transformGlobal2;
}
```

to mute music of my music app on incoming calls. but it is triggered as well when you press the off or menu button of the phone. Is there a way to leave the off button and menu button do their own normal thing? while having this code only affecting incoming calls?

Comment: You may want to use <pre> tags to format your code. What you have now is illegible.

Comment: sorry bout that. Thanks for pointing it out..